# How Can I get unique tuple in pandas Multi index from_product

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have to compare employees from both data frames
So I'm creating a multi index to calculate the fuzzy score between both of them

```
 df = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1['employee'],df2['employee']]).to_series().reset_index()
 from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
 from fuzzywuzzy import process
 df.apply(lambda x:fuzz.ratio(x['employee'],x['employee']),axis =1)
```

Here I'm getting two instances of each pair from_product ?

('john','joe')
('joe','john')

How can I accomplish only one pair since fuzzy score will be same for both the pairs

Answer (score 0):

assuming that all the pairs are in a column named 'pairs', you can create a new column with these ordered and drop duplicates by it, something along the lines of:

```
df['ordered_pairs'] = [' '.join(sorted(x)) for x in df['pairs']]
df.drop_duplicates('ordered_pairs',inplace=True)
```

if you don't have them in a column, you can make one by using reset_index and zipping columns

Comment: Sorted works fine,but it is creating a list . So in drop duplicates it is throwing an error 'Unhashable list'

Comment: sorry, haven't seen your comment, you are right. if you don't have a solution yet you could use join on the list to make it a string, see my edit